# Qt Creator - копирования и использование библиотек вне Qt

Tags: qt, библиотеки, qtcreator, лицензирование

Хотелось бы получить достаточно конкретный ответ на рад моих вопросов которые постараюсь описать ниже.

Работаю я с Qt и в нем пишу свою курсовую работу. Использую я в ней Qt, а именно QtGui/QFile/QTextStream (на данный момент).

Но увы, при создании релизной версии через MinGW компиляторы, при копировании exe файла программы в другое место программе не хватает Qt*Core.dll и Qt*Gui.dll файлов.

Соответственно если их найти и насильственно запихнуть в каталог к exe файл прогарммы - все работает (даже на виртуальной машине где Qt не установлен).

И вот на этом моменте у меня возник вопрос. Существеут же лицензия для Qt. Соответственно что-то да под эту лицензию подпадает.

**И вот конкретно мой вопрос:**
Если я эту свою папку с копиями dll от Qt скопирую себе на флушку и понесу куда-угодно и буду там запускать, будет ли это нарушением лицензии?

Ну и второй логичный вопрос: если да, если это нарушение, каким образом мне можно все же сделать свой независимый exe файл, что бы использовать его **для демонстрации**(!) на системах где не установлен Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> И вот конкретно мой вопрос: Если я эту свою папку с копиями dll от Qt
>   скопирую себе на флушку и понесу куда-угодно и буду там запускать,
>   будет ли это нарушением лицензии?

Нет.

Особенно для демонстрации, особенно если вы готовы предоставить исходники по первому требованию.

Лицензия Qt, в её OpenSource реализации - LGPL. Не в даваясь в подробности, то именно LGPL позволяет линковаться с закрытыми проектами, при условии, что вы можете обеспечить замену библиотеки другой версией. Динамическая линковка в этом вопросе очень выручает. Есть тонкий момент про обеспечение заменой на "модифифированую" версию библиотеки. Тут может поломаться ABI. Как следствие просто замена DLL может не пройти. А вот перелинковка - да. В таком случае нужно предоставить объектные файлы своего продукта и SDK (реальный, а не гипотетический) который позволит собрать из объектников и новой библиотеки новый exe. Собственно, таким образом можно даже статически линковаться с LGPL библиотекой закрытому проекту - гимора больше разработчику, но возможно.

В вашем случае ничего этого не нужно.

Собственно в [FAQ](http://www.qt.io/faq/) они это разобрали:

> **What are my obligations when using Qt under the LGPL?**
>
> If you are using Qt under the LGPL, there are a couple of obligations you will need to fulfill:
>
> - You will need to deliver the complete source code of Qt (including all modifications you did or applied) to your users/customers.
>     Alternatively you need to provide a written offer with instructions on
>     how to get the source code. Please also note that this has to be under
>     your control, so a link to the source code provided by the Qt Project
>     or Qt Company is not sufficient.

Сделали изменения в самом Qt - выложили. Иначе нарушаете. Плюс дали инструкции где скачать Qt и его исходники. Или сами поставляете.

> - The LGPL allows you to keep the source code of your application private as long as it is “work that uses” the library. Dynamic linking
>     is usually recommended here.

Собственно про это я выше и написал. Динамическая линковка - ваш друг (но враг размера дистрибуции - с чем-то нужно мириться).

> - The user of your application has to be able to re-link your application against a different or modified version of the Qt library.
>     With LGPLv3 it is also explicitly stated that the user needs to be
>     able to run the re-linked binary on it’s intended target device. It is
>     your obligation to provide the user with all necessary tools to enable
>     this process. For embedded devices, this includes making the full
>     toolchain used to compile the library available to users. For parts
>     licensed under LGPLv3 you are obliged to provide full instructions on
>     how to install the modified library on the target device (this is not
>     clearly stated with LGPLv2.1, although running the application against
>     the modified version of the library clearly is the stated intention of
>     the license).

О, тот самый шикарный пункт про релинковку с другой версией библиотеки. По этому же принципу можно линковаться и статически.

> - The user of an application or device using LGPL licensed software has to be notified of their rights by providing a copy of the LGPL
>     license to the end user and displaying a prominent notice about your
>     usage of LGPL licensed software.

Это отразить в README или другой документации. Плюс добавить информацию о LGPL софте в About... или рядом.

Ну и снова: это имеет смысл, если вы решите распространять свой продукт. В вариантах proof-of-concept или демонстрации вас никто ни за что наказывать не будет, даже если вы все эти пункты нарушите.

Answer (score 0):

Если мне не изменяет память, Вы можете использовать свою программу с динамическими файлами библиотеки без особых ограничений. Для статической сборки требуется приобрести коммерческую лицензию Qt. Текст лицензии можно посмотреть на сайте qt.io и в папке Licenses установки.

Comment: Про статику вы не совсем правы.